# Debian KVM guest unbootable after mkinitramfs - mounting /dev/vda1 on /root failed

Tags: linux, grub2, kvm, qemu

**07/07/20 Edited: added info regarding problem scope**

**25/06/20 Edited: added some additional diag information**

I have an issue where a **Debian** KVM guest built using `virt-resize` will work flawlessly up until `mkinitramfs` is run (Kernel upgrade, Grub cfg change, etc), after which the system fails to boot.

- Grub menu appears
- Any selected option from the menu then results in the system failing to the initramfs Busybox shell with an error:

`mount: mounting /dev/vda1 on /root failed: No such device`

I have taken a copy of the guest prior to this condition, and one post, then booted each passing the `break=premount` kernel option to force them both out into the initramfs debug shell. From there I have tried comparing what is different. Most notable is the output of `dmesg`. It is basically identical right up until the end. On the bad host:

**Broken Host**

```
[    0.743940] Run /init as init process
[    0.801833] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: I/O space for GPIO uninitialized
[    0.814263] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    0.817594] input: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
[    0.817785] input: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input2
[    0.820087] PCI Interrupt Link [GSIA] enabled at IRQ 16
[    0.820187] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[    0.829008] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    0.829008] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    0.839844] virtio_blk virtio2: [vda] 41943040 512-byte logical blocks (21.5 GB/20.0 GiB)
[    0.843734]  vda: vda1 vda2
[    0.846319] virtio_net virtio0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
```

**Working Host**

```
[    0.736291] Run /init as init process
[    0.795060] lpc_ich 0000:00:1f.0: I/O space for GPIO uninitialized
[    0.800259] PCI Interrupt Link [GSIA] enabled at IRQ 16
[    0.800363] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI interrupt
[    0.811428] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    0.821407] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    0.821407] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    0.823702] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.823712] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.823717] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.823726] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.829766] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.830240] input: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
[    0.830430] input: VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input2
[    0.844882] virtio_blk virtio2: [vda] 41943040 512-byte logical blocks (21.5 GB/20.0 GiB)
[    0.854231]  vda: vda1 vda2
[    0.857633] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.857638] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.857900] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: hcc params 0x00087001 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000000000010
[    0.859088] virtio_net virtio0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0
[    0.860055] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.19
[    0.860056] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.860056] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.860057] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 xhci-hcd
[    0.860057] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:02:00.0
...
```

I have trimmed the latter a bit, cos it is just goes on to load and initialise a bunch of IO as you would expect, where the broken host does not.

`lsmod` on the broken host confirms the SCSI module is not loaded. `modprobe -v scsi_mod` does not load the module or produce any output either directly or in `dmesg`.

**Problem Scope**

Through testing, I have managed to narrow down that only Debian guests are effected, and only on guests that have been created using `virt-resize`.

Debian hosts have no issues if I simply clone the base LVM volume, however  using `virt-resize` to copy the contents of the base LVM volume to another (larger) volume, which is what I do in my build script, this issue is then triggered. Debian has a wrapper script around mkinitramfs called update-initramfs.

CentOS hosts have no issues, irrespective of build method.

Not really sure what to make of this. It seems that something is different/broken in the initramfs.

**======== Guest Build Method =========**

Prereq: A base Debian guest is manually installed using a very small LVM backed 3G disk (2 partitions = / & swap). This has a bunch of very basic config applied (Ansible user created, a few key packages installed, IPV6 disabled, etc).

Then when the script runs:

- An LVM snapshop is taken of the volume backing the base image
- `kpartx -a /path/to/snapshot` is run to get access at the partitions
- 2 files are edited on the extracted root partition to set network params
- `kpartx -d /path/to/snapshot`
- A new LVM volume is create at the size that the finished guest should have (e.g. 20G)
- `virt-resize` is run using the snapshot as the source and the new volume as the target. The contained swap partition is resized to a fixed size with the `--resize` option and the root partition is to grown to fill remaining space with the `--expand` option.
- `kpartx -a` is again used to extract the partitions from the new volume so `mkswap` can be run on the newly sized swap partition, and then `kpartx -d` to clean up
- Suitable config is added to KVM for the new guest with the new volume as its disk

This all works fine. The guest works fine, right up until the first time `mkinitramfs` runs on the guest.

Does anybody have any thoughts/ideas on what might be happening and how it could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your USB drivers aren't loading. Not sure why that would be causing a problem with your virtual drive (VirtIO drivers still appear to be there), but that's the main difference between the two dmesg commands.

The other difference is that the SCSI subsystem isn't loading in the broken VM. You said that this problem doesn't occur when you just run mkinitramfs on the base image, but that it does break everything after your script runs. Maybe it has something to do with your usage of LVM? Try executing one line of your script at a time by hand, running mkinitramfs, and then rebooting. This should help you pinpoint the problem.

Sorry about this short and maybe not very helpful answer - I made a massive answer about VirtIO driver installation and whatnot, realized I had missed a line in one of your dmesg dumps, which completely undid my whole solution, and then discovered you couldn't delete an answer from Stack Exchange, so I had to keep something up, and I didn't want to leave a misleading (and totally useless) answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time. I will update the Q, but further testing shows a) virt-resize is the trigger and b) only Debian guests are effected. It is really odd :(